# Counting occurrences using Toxi solution

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I'm new to `mysql`.

I wanted to develop a simple tagging system for my blog and came across this "Toxi" Solution of making 3 tables.

So, I have 3 tables:

```
`blog` containing `id` and `title`. 
`blog_tags` containing `id` and `tags_id` and `blog_id`.
`tags` containing `id` and `name`.
```

`tags_id` is connected to `Internal Relation` to `id` in `tags` table.
Similarly, `blog_id` is connected to `Internal Relation` to `id` in `blog` table.

So, when in my function (where I get the array of all tags pertaining to a single blog) I execute a query for example (passing blog `id` as the parameter in the function),

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT tags_id FROM blog_tags WHERE blog_id = '".$id."'");
    $tags = array();
    if($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tags[] = I don't know what should come over here?   
    }
    return $tags;
```

Or is there any other way to execute queries in this Toxi implementation?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is there a problem with that approach?

Comment: @peterm: What should be in this line: `$tags[]=??`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** You need  a simple `JOIN`. Your query should look like

```sql
SELECT bt.tags_id, t.name
  FROM blog_tags bt JOIN tags t
    ON bt.tags_id = t.id
 WHERE bt.blog_id = n -- < n is an id of a blog
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4a7c/3)** demo.

Now php is pretty straightforward

```php
$sql = "SELECT bt.tags_id, t.name
          FROM blog_tags bt JOIN tags t
            ON bt.tags_id = t.id
         WHERE bt.blog_id = $id";     
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
$tags = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tags[] = $row['name'];  
}
...
```

**On a side note:** switch to PDO or mysqli. mysql_* extension is deprecated. In PDO you can use a syntactic sugar [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). And more importantly learn to use prepared statements. Right now your code is vulnerable to sql-injections.

Comment: But this will give me `tags_id`, I wanted to store `name` of tags from `tags` table in `$tags` array. I could perform two nested queries but that would have `O(^2)`. I guess there should be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: @ptokya You were very unclear on that point in your question. But anyway see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, for the poor framing of the question.